# Why does my bash for loop hang at a command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using [entr](http://eradman.com/entrproject/entr.1.html) to check if new files are added to certain subdirectories, and run a command if such an event occurs. If I have a directory with folders: `folder`, `prefix_folder1`, and `prefix_folder2`, then I want to monitor the presence of new files within a certain subdirectory in the latter two, i.e., monitor `prefix_folder1/subdir` and `prefix_folder2/subdir`

This is my current approach with an infinite loop:

```sh
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3 trap "exit" INT # in case of ^C
  4 while true
  5 do
  6     for stage in $(ls '/Users/me/test')
  7     do
  8         if [[ "$stage" == "prefix"* ]]; then #check for prefix
  9             ls -d * /Users/me/test/$stage/subdir | entr -pd echo hey
 10 
 11         fi
 12     done
 13 done
```

However for each directory, the script hangs at line 9 until a new file is created. E.g., if it is at `prefix_folder2/subdir` it will not `echo` "hey" if a file is created in `prefix_folder1/subdir`.

My understanding of bash for loops is limited in this scenario and I'm not sure what keywords to look up to find a solution for this.

Comment: That's how `entr` works. It just keeps waiting for changes to the files and executes the command whenever something happens.

Comment: Why are you listing `*` in addition to `/Users/me/test/$stage/subdir`?

Comment: Why are you using a loop instead of passing all the directory names to `entr` at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
while true
do
    ls -d /Users/me/test/prefix*/subdir | entr -pd echo hey
done
```

This will pass all the directories you want to monitor at once to a single invocation of `entr`, rather than calling it separately for each directory.

You don't need to include `*` in the `ls` command, as that will also monitor all the files in the current directory.